# How to install R 3.2.2 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install R 3.2.2 in ubuntu 16.04 but I can only get the 3.3.3 version with the regular installation. I can only work with that version, but I can't find how to do it in intertnet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652219/installing-older-version-of-r

Comment: This RStudio support blog post might be helpful as well [Installing multiple versions of R on Linux](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215488098-Installing-multiple-versions-of-R-on-Linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find old versions of R [here](https://cran.r-project.org/sources.html). You have to install it manually. In the tar.gz file is a `INSTALL` file on how to install it.

Comment: Great. That did it.