# Unable to Install Older Version of R

Tags: r, unix, installation

I am trying to install and older version of R (3.2.1), and am following the instructions on this page: https://www.miskatonic.org/2015/06/23/installing-r-from-source/

As suggested by the webpage, I uninstalled R

```
usr@ubuntu:/usr/lib/R/R-3.2.1$ R
The program 'R' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install r-base-core
```

And I am fairly positive that "make" is installed:

```
usr@ubuntu:/usr/lib/R/R-3.2.1$ sudo apt-get install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
make is already the newest version (4.1-6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

When I run

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```

I get the following (I am not sure what is normal and what is an error message). In addition, the following files are created: Makeconf.in, Makefile.fw, Makefile.in

```
usr@ubuntu:/usr/lib/R/R-3.2.1$ sudo ./configure 
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
loading site script './config.site'
loading build-specific script './config.site'
checking for pwd... /bin/pwd
checking whether builddir is srcdir... yes
checking for working aclocal... found
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake... found
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for which... /usr/bin/which
checking for less... /usr/bin/less
checking for gtar... no
checking for gnutar... no
checking for tar... /bin/tar
checking for tex... no
checking for pdftex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals
checking for pdflatex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
checking for makeindex... no
checking for texi2any... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
checking for texi2dvi... no
checking for kpsewhich... no
checking for latex inconsolata package... checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
checking for gzip... /bin/gzip
checking for bzip2... /bin/bzip2
checking for firefox... /usr/bin/firefox
using default browser ... /usr/bin/firefox
checking for acroread... no
checking for acroread4... no
checking for xdg-open... /usr/bin/xdg-open
checking for notangle... false
checking for realpath... /usr/bin/realpath
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for f95... f95
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... yes
checking whether f95 accepts -g... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -fvisibility... yes
checking whether f95 accepts -fvisibility... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... no
checking whether gcc accepts -g... no
checking for Objective C++ compiler... trying some possibilities
checking whether g++ can compile ObjC++... no
checking whether  can compile ObjC++... no
no working ObjC++ compiler found
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether f95 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for f95 option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if f95 PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if f95 static flag -static works... yes
checking if f95 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if f95 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the f95 linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for sin in -lm... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking readline/history.h usability... no
checking readline/history.h presence... no
checking for readline/history.h... no
checking readline/readline.h usability... no
checking readline/readline.h presence... no
checking for readline/readline.h... no
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for main in -lncurses... yes
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for history_truncate_file... no
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available

usr@ubuntu:/usr/lib/R/R-3.2.1$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I also tried following the instructions here: [Installing older version of R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652219/installing-older-version-of-r), but the R version 3.2.1 is NOT listed in the directory (xenial).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can finish installing this version of R? I appreciate the help - ahhn

**EDIT:**
I am now receiving the following when I get to the "./configure" step:

```
usr@ubuntu:~/Downloads/R-3.2.1$ ./configure --prefix=/home/usr/Downloads/R3.2.1_VERSION --enable-R-shlib --with-blas --with-lapack
    checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    loading site script './config.site'
    loading build-specific script './config.site'
    checking for pwd... /bin/pwd
    checking whether builddir is srcdir... yes
    checking for working aclocal... found
    checking for working autoconf... found
    checking for working automake... found
    checking for working autoheader... found
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking for bison... no
    checking for byacc... no
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking for sed... /bin/sed
    checking for which... /usr/bin/which
    checking for less... /usr/bin/less
    checking for gtar... no
    checking for gnutar... no
    checking for tar... /bin/tar
    checking for tex... no
    checking for pdftex... no
    configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals
    checking for pdflatex... no
    configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
    checking for makeindex... no
    checking for texi2any... no
    configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
    checking for texi2dvi... no
    checking for kpsewhich... no
    checking for latex inconsolata package... checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
    checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
    checking for gzip... /bin/gzip
    checking for bzip2... /bin/bzip2
    checking for firefox... /usr/bin/firefox
    using default browser ... /usr/bin/firefox
    checking for acroread... no
    checking for acroread4... no
    checking for xdg-open... /usr/bin/xdg-open
    checking for notangle... false
    checking for realpath... /usr/bin/realpath
    checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
    checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for f95... f95
    checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... yes
    checking whether f95 accepts -g... yes
    checking for g++... g++
    checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
    checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
    checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
    checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -fvisibility... yes
    checking whether f95 accepts -fvisibility... yes
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking minix/config.h usability... no
    checking minix/config.h presence... no
    checking for minix/config.h... no
    checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... no
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... no
    checking for Objective C++ compiler... trying some possibilities
    checking whether g++ can compile ObjC++... no
    checking whether  can compile ObjC++... no
    no working ObjC++ compiler found
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
    checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
    checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
    checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
    checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
    checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
    checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
    checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
    checking for objdump... objdump
    checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
    checking for strip... strip
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
    checking for dlfcn.h... yes
    checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
    checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
    checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
    checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... (cached) yes
    checking whether f95 accepts -g... (cached) yes
    checking for objdir... .libs
    checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
    checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... no
    checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
    checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... no
    checking for f95 option to produce PIC... -fPIC
    checking if f95 PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
    checking if f95 static flag -static works... yes
    checking if f95 supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if f95 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the f95 linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking for cos in -lm... yes
    checking for sin in -lm... yes
    checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
    checking readline/history.h usability... no
    checking readline/history.h presence... no
    checking for readline/history.h... no
    checking readline/readline.h usability... no
    checking readline/readline.h presence... no
    checking for readline/readline.h... no
    checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
    checking for main in -lncurses... yes
    checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
    checking for history_truncate_file... no
    configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
    usr@ubuntu:~/Downloads/R-3.2.1$ make
    make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

**EDIT 2:**
I am running into errors when I try to install readline-devel and xorg-dev:

```
usr@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install readline-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package readline-devel

usr@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xorg-dev : Depends: libxaw7-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcursor-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxfont-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxft-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxpm-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: xserver-xorg-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: This RStudio support blog post might be helpful as well [Installing multiple versions of R on Linux](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215488098-Installing-multiple-versions-of-R-on-Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following steps:

First make sure if you have libxt-dev and jdk.

```
dpkg -l <package name>
```

If not do these following commands:

```
sudo apt -f install && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install fort77
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev  libblas-dev gfortran
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
sudo apt-get install gobjc++
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libreadline-dev
sudo apt-get install libxt-dev
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Then download your preferred R version and do as follows:

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.2.1.tar.gz
mkdir R-3.2.1
mv R-3.2.1.tar.gz R-3.2.1/
cd R-3.2.1/
tar -xzvf R-3.2.1.tar.gz
```

Next, make another folder for R's binary version and use the  to that folder here:

```
mkdir <full path>/R3.2.1_VERSION
```

Build R from source, please make sure to add the full path in prefix

```
./configure --prefix=<full path>/R3.2.1_OLDERVERSION --enable-R-shlib --with-blas --with-lapack
make
sudo make install
```

Once, you are finished, please set the environment variable to make sure the right version of R is called

```
export PATH=<full path>/R3.2.1_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

If everything went smoothly then you can see your current R version as 3.2.1 when you run R.
If you want to switch to another version of R then change the environment variable to your preferred version of R package in your account as follows:

```
export PATH=<full path>/R<your preferred>_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Made edit to question with new error message. Additionally, does it matter what the <file path> is?

Comment: Would adding this to the ./configure  line {{ --with-readline=no --with-x=no }} fix the problem? from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473547/error-with-readline-yes-default-and-headers-libs-are-not-available

Comment: I have adjusted my answer above.